# Vertical scroll in a ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, scrollbar

Hi I have a list box as below inside a grid. I cant make the items inside the ListBox scrollable when the number of items exceed the height of the ListBox.

I added `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"` to the ListBox tag but it doesn't work at all.

Read somewhere about scrolling doesnt work in a stack panel.

Anyone can help me with this? Thanks in advance!

```
<ListBox>
    <TreeView>
       <TreeView.Resources>
           <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
               <StackPanel>
                 <TextBlock />
                 <TextBox></TextBox>
               </StackPanel>
           </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
       </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the ScrollView property:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
         ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">     
    <TreeView>
        <TreeView.Resources>            
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate>                
                <StackPanel>                  
                    <TextBlock/>                    
                    <TextBox></TextBox>                
                </StackPanel>            
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>        
        </TreeView.Resources>     
    </TreeView> 
</ListBox>
```

It Should work...

Comment: hmm I tried that. Its not working though.

I added Focusable="False" MaxHeight="500" to the ListBox tag. Does any of these attributes might have contribute to the problem?

Comment: Could you post the Layout i.e Xaml

Comment: oh i solved it already. Apparently the treeview is being wrapped inside the listbox and i am actually adding the scrollbar to the listbox instead.

so i remove the listbox and it works! thanks!

Comment: I thought you wanted to make a Hierarchial Listbox (Like blend)